# Informatica Task error: [Error: Source Qualifier Transformation at running

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We create informatica Power Center workflow. when we run it at first time and some times second times it succeeded but it failed after that with this error [error: [Error: Source Qualifier Transformation at running ]

[image]

Comment: You are using java transformation?

Comment: No, i using informatica TDM and it generate power Center package automatic.

Comment: what is your source? can you post a full log?